# setter injection in XML not working when assigning values

Tags: java, xml, spring, code-injection, setter

I am practicing Spring and I created 2 objects(Captain, BlackWidow) for which i defined values using property name and value in my xml file


as per my knowledge the name attribute will call the **setName(String name)** methods on both classes and will pass the values *Natasha* and *Captain* to the setName methods. However, when i call these methods, they don't seem to return any value.
here is my code:

Captain class:

```
package com.tutorialspoit;

public class Captain {

private String name;

      public Captain() {
          System.out.println("Captain constructor");
         }

      public String getName() {
          return this.name;
         }

      public void setName(String name) {
       this.name=name;
        }
   }
```

Avengers class, from which i call the getName() methods from the Captain class:

```
package com.tutorialspoit;

public class Avengers {

    private Captain steve;
    private BlackWidow natasha;

    public Avengers() {
        System.out.println("Avengers constructor");

    }
    public void setCaptain(Captain cap){
        this.steve=cap;
        }
    public String getCaptain() {
        return steve.getName();
    }

    public void setBlackWidow(BlackWidow bw){
        this.natasha=bw;
        }
    public String getBlackWidow() {
        return natasha.getName();
    }

}
```

then, here it is my Avengers class:

```
import org.springframework.context.support.*;

public class MainAvengers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
                ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Avengers avg = context.getBean("myAssembly", Avengers.class);
        avg.getCaptain();
        avg.getBlackWidow();
        context.close();
    }
}
```

and finally my applicationContext.xml file:

```
   <bean id="myAssembly" class="com.tutorialspoit.Avengers">
    <property name="captain" ref="steve_rogers"/>
    <property name="blackWidow" ref="natasha_romanov"/>

    </bean>
    <bean id="natasha_romanov" class="com.tutorialspoit.BlackWidow">
    <property name="name" value="Natasha"/>

    </bean>
    <bean id="steve_rogers" class="com.tutorialspoit.Captain">
    <property name="name" value="Captain"/>
    </bean>
```

when I compile it, it compiles fine, but it doesn't show me the name that i defined in my xml file:

[image]

so, my question is, am I assigning the name of my objects correctly? why are the objects are being created but names are not being assigned to them?

any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: If you want to practice with Spring, don't use XML configuration; it's nearly obsolete. Use JavaConfig Spring Boot instead. With JavaConfig, this becomes simply `@Bean public Captain steveRogers() { Captain c = new Captain(); c.setName("Steve Rogers"); return c; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your code is correct , you're just didnt making the right thing that you want in main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
Avengers avg = context.getBean("myAssembly", Avengers.class); // 1
avg.getCaptain(); //2
avg.getBlackWidow(); //3
context.close();
```

}

In 1,2,3 you're just calling the objects , **which calls only the default constructor** , that's why you're getting only as output `Class contructor` just like your print in the default constructor method

So if you want the names , you have to simply **print the getters**